# Buttons are ui-btn-inline but no inline behavior in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a header with 2 rows. The first row is a ui-grid-solo and the second row is a ui-grid-c. However I have some problems with the first row. Even if buttons are using the class ui-btn-inline, they don't behave like they're inline. I would like to have the first button on the left, in the middle the title, and right the other button. It seems I'm providing the wrong style for  or maybe something else.

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" id="main">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <div class="ui-grid-solo">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <input type="button" value="Menu" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-delete" onclick='btn_menupanel();'/>
                <h6 id="begin" class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Title</h6>
                <input type="button" value="Info" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check" onclick='$("#infopanel").panel("open");'/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid-c">
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="background-color:red">
                    A
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="background-color:yellow">
                    B
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c" id="div-current-test" style="background-color:blue">
                    C
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-d" id="div-status" style="background-color:green">
                    D
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /header -->
</div>
```

Here the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/8jkdz8jf/2/

I'm using jqm 1.4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <!-- try this out -->
  <div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" id="main">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <a href="#" type="button" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-delete" /> Menu </a>
                    <h6 id="begin" class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Title</h6>
                    <a href="#" type="button" value="Info" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check" /> Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ui-grid-c">
                <div class="ui-block-a" style="background-color:red">
                        A
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b" style="background-color:yellow">
                        B
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c" id="div-current-test" style="background-color:blue">
                        C
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d" id="div-status" style="background-color:green">
                        D
                </div>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->

        </div><!-- /header -->
    </div>
```